# C# Count items Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have model with 3 fields : `TItle`, `Body`, `Status`.

```
 public class Names
    {   [PrimaryKey]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public string Status{ get; set; }}
```

When user opens the page he can see list of names with fields (`Title`, `Body`).
Code of page looks like:

**xaml.cs**

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Models.Names> items { get; set; }

        public HomePage()
        {
            items = new ObservableCollection<Models.Names>();
            this.BindingContext = this;
            InitializeComponent();
            List.ItemSelected += (sender, e) => {
                ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
            };
            List.Refreshing += (sender, e) => {
                LoadUsersData();
            };
            LoadUsersData();
        }
        public async void LoadUsersData()
        {
            List.IsRefreshing = true;
            var Names= await App.Database.Names.GetItemsAsync();
            items.Clear();
            foreach (var item in Names)
                items.Add(item);
            List.IsRefreshing = false;
        }
    }
```

**xaml**

```
   <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="List"
                  HasUnevenRows="True"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding items}"
                  IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell 
                        Text="{Binding Title}" 
                        Detail="{Binding Body}"
                        TextColor="Black"
                        DetailColor="Gray">
                    </TextCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
```

In the begin of page I want to add string which shows amount of all items with `Status` = "New".
How I can do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `Label` that binds to the `Count` property of your `ObservableCollection` (it will be notified each time items are added/deleted from your collection):

```
<Label Text="{Binding items.Count, StringFormat='Status = {0}'}"/>
```

#### Update

If you need custom properties, like the number of `Names` objects with a `Status` of "new", there are multiple ways to create bindable properties, but one way is to subclass `ObservableCollection` and add your custom property:

```
public class MyObservableCollection : ObservableCollection<Names>
{
    public MyObservableCollection()
    {
        CollectionChanged += (object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) =>
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("NewCount"));
        };
    }

    public int NewCount
    {
        get { return this.Count((Names arg) => arg.Status == "new"); }
    }
}
```

Now replace your use of `ObservableCollection` with `MyObservableCollection`.

```
public MyObservableCollection items { get; set; }
```

In your XAML, you can now bind on `NewCount`:

```
<Label Text="{Binding items.Count, StringFormat='Status = {0}'}"/>
<Label Text="{Binding items.NewCount, StringFormat='Status = {0}'}"/>
```

In terms using a `BindableProperty` instead, there are other SO question/answers already posted and a great blog post:

- https://xamarinhelp.com/bindable-properties-xamarin-forms/

Comment: Thank you so much, it works.
1 small question, If I need to get 2 labels, for example: 1 lable will count items in list where status of names = "new" and next label will count items in list where status of names = "old", does it mean that I need to add 2 more ObservableCollections and filter them for each label result?

Comment: Or there can be better ways to do it?

Comment: @Dmitry There is a better way then maintaining multiple collections, see my answer for the update...

Comment: Did you try using Linq?

Comment: @SushiHangover It works great, thank you again for great answer.